# NSArray from URL encoding problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa, character-encoding

So I have the following code:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baseurltoanxmlpage.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"page.php" relativeToURL:baseURL];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

If the XML page is as follows:

```
<array><dict><key>City</key><string>Montreal</string></dict></array>
```

The array returns fine. However, if the XML file is as follows:

```
<array><dict><key>City</key><string>Montréal</string></dict></array>
```

The array returns null. I guess this has something to do with the special char "é".
How would I deal with these characters? The XML page is generated with PHP. utf8_encode() function makes the array return but then I don't know how to deal with the encoded "é" character.

**Here's the working solution:**

```
NSString *stringArray = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *array = [stringArray propertyList];

NSLog(stringArray);
NSLog(@"%@", array);
NSLog([[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"City"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

The first log prints out the "é" fine.
In the second log, it's encoded and is printed as "\U00e9". 
In the 3rd log, it's decoded and printed as "é" (which is what I was looking for).

Comment: Instead of `encoding:4`, you might want to use `encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`. You never know if Apple might change that 4 to something else. See http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringEncoding for NSStringEncoding types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you need to return a UTF8- or UTF16-encoded XML document. Then make `NSString` objects using the [`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BCIECHFE) method, using the relevant encoding.

Comment: As I wrote in my updated post, the NSString now gets the string fine. However when I return it as a propertyList, the special character is lost.

Comment: Looks like I forgot what an encoding was :( 
Thanks a lot for your help Alex!

Answer (score 1):

NSString has a [method to return data in encoding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:), data read from the URL:

+(id)stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:

Look under [String Encodings](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringEncoding) section for possible encodings to find the one suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `NSString` documentation for [`:propertyList`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-propertyList), we see:

- `Parses the receiver as a text representation of a property list, returning an NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary object, according to the topmost element.`

A [property list](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2) is an Apple-specific document that stores representations of `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, and other core types in XML format. These `.plist` files are usually used for storing preferences or application settings.

This XML-formatted property list document is encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), by default. When you turn your `NSString` into a property list element, encoding the `"é"` character replaces it with the [UTF-8 Unicode character `"\U00e9"`](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/output-french-characters-to-the-console.html).

Comment: Your previous answer was to use the stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method. Therefore I assume I first do [NSString stringFromContentsOfURL] and then stringByReplacing... But how do I transfer that string into an array? I thought propertyList: was the way to go but I just can't find any other method that does that.

Comment: Look into NSArray and NSMutableArray if you want to store NSString objects in an array. An NSString itself is not an array (at least, not in the manner you probably mean it).